# Vue.js, How to send object in api link via axios?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios

So I have `GET|HEAD` api: `api/users/{user}`, and it calls function `App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController@show`.
This function in Laravel is:

```
   public function show($id){
    return new UserShowResource(User::findOrFail($id));
}
```

How to send variable `id` to my function. I found somewhere this:

```
const helpVar = axios.get('/api/users/{this.$route.params.id}').then(response => {
           this.users = response.data;
           this.loading = false;
             
        });
```

But it does not work. I tried `axios.get('/api/users/1')` and it returns me user with `id=1`, so problem is with this link in axios.

Comment: what  is `{this.$route.params.id}` output?

Comment: I did `console.log(this.$route.params.id}` and it returns 1 (Or some other number, depends on the user id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't working because your are using simple quotation marks. As you are trying to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#expression_interpolation) for interpolating you must change your code to:

```js
const helpVar = axios.get(`/api/users/${this.$route.params.id}`).then(response => {
           this.users = response.data;
           this.loading = false;
             
        });
```

- Notice the change of '' to ``

Comment: For the future people who will find this question, there should be $ before {this...} so full correct syntax is: axios.get(`/api/users/${this.$route.params.id}`)

Comment: Thanks @Raskoljnikovic , been using C# and forgot to add the `$`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ` instead of ' so its possible to pass {this.$route.params.id} ;

```
const helpVar = axios.get(`/api/users/{this.$route.params.id}`).then(response => {
           this.users = response.data;
           this.loading = false;
             
        });
```